# To use Multistorage for each Group in Pig

Tags: nested, apache-pig

I am trying to group my data and store in hdfs with a folder for each 'name' and subfolders for each 'YearMonth' under each name folder.

Input:

```
(Date)        (name)         (col3)     (col4)

2015-02-02    abc              y          z

2016-01-02    xyz              i          j

2015-03-02    abc              f          b

2015-02-06    abc              y          z

2016-03-02    xyz              a          q
```

Expected out in hdfs:

**abc** folder

```
->201502 subfolder

       2015-02-02    abc              y          z

       2015-02-06    abc              y          z

->201503 subfolder

       2015-03-02    abc              f           b
```

**xyz** folder

```
->201601 subfolder

      2016-01-02    xyz              i            j

->201603 subfolder

      2016-03-02    xyz              a          q
```

I am not sure of how to use the Multistorage option on Name column after grouping the tuples by date.

Answer (score 0):

First create two relations by filtering by name

You can use substring to create a new field for DATE subfolder

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING($0,0,4),SUBSTRING($0,5,7)
```

Now use this to field as folder name in MultiStorage

Comment: I have a big set of data which millions of rows and more than a 100 names. Could you suggest what can I do in such a scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you want multiple level of folder (one for name and one for date). filtering and then using the only option. other options is to create a string with date and name something like "xyz/201503" and pass it to mutiStorage as folder name not sure whether that will work.

Comment: I am using split twice and then Mutistorage over it.
But too many multistorage commands
Is there a way to loop this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have HCatalog you can follow these steps:

1. Create partitioned table as below using HCatalog

   hcat -e "create external table TABLE_NAME (col3 string, col4 string) partitioned by (date string, name string) location '/user/$USER/multi_partition'"
2. Load Data to that table using following pig statements :

   A = LOAD 'Input.dat' using PigStorage() as (date:chararray, name:chararray, col3:chararray, col4:chararray);

   STORE A INTO 'TABLE_NAME' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();